# Upgrade Dnn 5 to Dnn7 now page names with dashes not matching static links

Tags: asp.net, url, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

So I upgraded a very large DNN5 site to DNN7 for a client. Now all static links in the page content that point to page names with dashes are broken.

so the page name is **Mid-Size Truck** in the CMS

the static link from the old site that worked is www.somesite.com/**MidSizeTruck**.aspx

the upgraded dnn is now calling the link www.somesite.com/**Mid-SizeTruck**.aspx

so now when you click on the old static link it cant find the new page urls that have the dash included. There are thousands of these static links, is there a way to get DNN to remove the dashes like it use to?

I did however notice if the there is a space on both sides of the dash in the page name, dnn removes it from the url.

so     **ch1 - First Article**

becomes 
    /**ch1FirstArticle**.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Did you switch to the Advanced URL Provider (which is a web.config change)?  Otherwise, I wouldn't expect the URLs to change.

There's a `TabUrl` table that has been introduced, which lets you specify URL aliases for pages (which will 301 redirect to the "real" URL).  However, you may need to switch to the advanced URL provider to do that (which is theoretically unsafe since it might change URLs, but since it's mismatched, may not be any worse).  To do that switch, find the `<friendlyUrl />` element in the web.config, then change the `urlFormat` attribute to `advanced` for the `DNNFriendlyUrl` entry.

If `DNNFriendlyUrl` isn't the default friendly URL provider (e.g. you're using iFinity's 3rd party URL provider), that may be part of the issue, as well.  At that point, you'd need to do some research with the developer of that URL provider.